# Finding $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x}$ without L'Hopital and series expansion.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

So we have to find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x}$ without using any series expansions or the L'Hopital's rule.
I did it using both but I have no idea how to do it. I tried many substitutions but nothing worked. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: How do you define $a^x$?

Comment: What do you mean by defining $a^x$?

Comment: It is any number raised to a varying power. In general we have to find- $\frac{a^x+n}{x}$

Comment: I mean that without a definition to start with (for example defining $e^x$ as the solution to $y'=y$, or the inverse of $\int_1^x \frac{\mathrm dt}{t}$, etc), there's not much you can say about the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x=\log_a(t)$$

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 1}\frac{t-1}{\log_at}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 1}\frac{(t-1)\log(a)}{\log(t)}=\log(a)$$
EDIT:

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\log(x)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_0^x \frac 1x\frac{dt}{1+t}$$
Put: $t=xs$ then:
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_0^1 \frac{ds}{1+xs}=\int_0^1ds=1$$

Also:
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(1+x)-\log(1)}{(x+1)-1}=(\log(x))'_{x=1}=1$$

Comment: How did you deduce the last step?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal added some explanation.

Comment: I didnt understand how you transformed the limit into integral?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I didn't turn the limit into an integral, I used the following well-known fact: $$\log(1+x)=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t}$$

Comment: Alternatively, you can express $\frac{\log x}{x-1}$ as $\log(x^{1/(x-1)})$ and do the change $x=t+1$. It gives $\log((t+1)^{1/t})$. Hence, by use of the definition of $e$ as limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log x}{x-1}=\lim_{t\to 0}\log((t+1)^{1/t})=1.
$$

Answer (score 4):

In order to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^{x} - 1}{x}\tag{1}$$ for $a > 0$, it is necessary to have a proper definition of $a^{x}$. This has been pointed out in one of the comments to the question, but OP has perhaps not understood the necessity of such a comment. In case you want to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x} - 1}{x - 1}$$ it is necessary to have a definition of the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ and it is easy to define it by saying that *$\sqrt{x}$ is a non-negative real number which gives $x$ when squared*.

The unfortunate part here is that there is no definition of $a^{x}$ which is as simple as the definition of $\sqrt{x}$ and most introductory calculus texts try their best not to define this symbol in proper manner. The *real sin* is committed when they are able to convince the students that there is no necessity of such a definition. It is one thing to avoid a complicated definition but totally another matter to convince that such a thing does not exist.

There are multiple approaches to define $a^{x}$ and almost all of them are hard enough for a beginner in calculus (see [these](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-1.html) [posts](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html) [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html) in case you are interested).

---

I prefer the following approach which is suitable for a beginner in calculus:

**Theorem**: *For a given real number $a > 0$ there exists a unique function $F(x)$ defined and continuous for all real $x$ such that $F(0) = 1, F(1) = a$ and $F(x + y) = F(x)F(y)$ for all $x, y$. Moreover if $x$ is a rational number (say equal to $r \in \mathbb{Q}$) then $F(x) = F(r) = a^{r}$*.

This function is called the general exponential function and denoted by symbol $a^{x}$. And then we come to the limit in question:

**Theorem**: *For any real number $a > 0$ the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^{x} - 1}{x}$$ exists and hence defines a function of $a$ (say $L(a)$) and this function $L(a)$ satisfies the following properties: $$L(1) = 0, L(xy) = L(x) + L(y)$$ Further $L(x)$ is continuous for all $x > 0$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{L(1 + x)}{x} = 1\tag{2}$$* The function $L$ is traditionally denoted by $\log x$ and is called the *natural logarithm* (or just the logarithm) of $x$.

---

Essentially the above approach gives two standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^{x} - 1}{x} = \log a,\,\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1$$ and defers their proof (to advanced courses). But it is more honest than supplying *vague ideas* and *intuition* about exponential and logarithmic functions which I consider more of a *[hand waving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwaving)*.

Comment: I read "the real sin" as "the $\sin \in \mathbb{R}$" ;)

Comment: @PatrickStevens: I like your sense of humor :):), but on a serious note such textbook authors are great sinners. I still remember my struggle with such books when I was 16 years of age. Luckily I did not have to struggle too much because I got the goldmine "A Course of Pure Mathematics" by G. H. Hardy a few months later.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try with substitution $x=\frac{t}{\log a}$

Using $a=e^{\log a}$ you obtain $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \left(\frac{a^{\frac{t}{\log a}}-1}{t}\right) \log a= \lim_{t\to \infty} \left(\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right) \log a= \log a$$

Comment: But limit of $\frac{e^t-1}{t}$ is the special case of limit I asked.

Comment: buy you need to use some knowledge of derivative of exponential function, exp is defined as function such that $ f'(x)=f(x) $ and $f(0) =1$ and i think $ f(x) \ge 1+x $ , with those 3 you can show that such function exist and its unique and its knows as $f(x)=e^x$

Comment: I haven't understood a half of what you wrote, @Jack. And I am saying that, how can you use derivatives, when the definition of the derivative uses my asked limit. And the limit of $e^x...$ is a special case.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal  just find how is $e^x$ defined $ [e^x]'(0) = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^{(0+t)}-e^{(t)}}{t}=e^0 $     whatever you do you will end up on something equivalent to this and this is how exp is defined

Answer (score 2):

It is precisely $f'(0)$, where $f(r) = a^r$.

Comment: But to find the derivative of $f(x)$, you use the limit I asked.

Comment: Then you should have said that you weren't allowed to use the chain rule :)

Comment: Chain rule's proof uses the definition of a limit.

Comment: I don't think, *then* it was necessary to be told that "you don't have to use the chain rule"

Comment: Chain rule's proof uses the definition of a limit, but doesn't require you to know the limits in question before using the chain rule.

Comment: See it like this, limit->definition->chain rule. Where -> is used by. Then how can we use chain rule for the limit?

Comment: Well, you're not going to get any proofs that don't use the concept of a limit.

Comment: I dont understand why people are voting up this answer. This is evidently circular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27301/discussion-between-patrick-stevens-and-aditya-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

Firt prove $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1$. In fact, let $y=e^x-1$, that is $x=\ln(1+y)$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}x=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{\ln(1+y)}
=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac1{\frac1y\ln(1+y)}=\frac1{\ln\left[\lim\limits_{y\to 0}
(1+y)^{1/y}\right]}=\frac1{\ln e}=1.$$
Then
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}x=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x\ln a}-1}{x}=
\ln a\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x\ln a-1}}{x\ln a}=\ln a.$$

Answer (score -1):

Convert it into standard limit as write $a^x$   as $e^{x\ln a}$ and
$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{x-1}}{x}=1$